# Importing posts in custom post type into new website

Tags: custom-post-types, bulk-import

I have two wordpress installs. One in root directory and other in subdirectory of the same domain. I want to transfer posts of subdirectory **into a custom post type of main site**. Post of subdirectory (to be transferred) have several taxonomies so should I import and transfer taxonomies first? If yes then how to? and do all this transfer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you should need to do is export from WP as you normally would if you were just transferring the content. Download the resulting XML file, change all `<wp:post_type>post</wp:post_type>` entries to `<wp:post_type>YOUR_CUSTOM_POST_TYPE</wp:post_type>`. This should work, assuming your Custom Post Type is already registered in the theme.

Comment: I have tried, it's not working.

Comment: What's not working? The export, or the import? And what do you mean by "not working" is it generating an error, or just not displaying the way you expect?

Comment: import is not working. I have exported data and changed the said line (post type name) and also registered that custom post type in new site but nothing displayed after importing.

Comment: There is an issue with export if you had selected a date range. Did you export `all` dates and choose just the custom posts?  And had you tried to change the <link> </link> in the XML file or did you leave those alone?

Comment: I am having the same issue with export working (I checked the XML) and import working (finishing successfully) but only the custom post type posts won't show up.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution. You have to go to Appearance -> Themes and click "Customize" for the theme that is currently activated and then choose the option to have a static front page and choose a page to be the blog page.

After I did that, all of my custom post type posts showed up and my home page wasn't broken anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I did something like this on a WordPress blog using a plugin ([Post Type Switcher](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-type-switcher/)) to change the type of the post. On Old WordPress website, I had Posts which I wanted to move to the new website under "**Blog**" custom post type.

The above plugin allows you to change **Post Type of imported posts**.